# Multiple <xsl:template match in .xslt file in mule

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, wsdl, mule

I use these codes for hiding my methods in my XML(WSDL) file:

```
    <xsl:template match="wsdl:operation[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIP']" />  
<xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapIn']" /> 
<xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapOut']" /> 

<xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetIn']" /> 
<xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetOut']" /> 

<xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostIn']" /> 
<xsl:template match="wsdl:message[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpPostOut']" /> 

<xsl:template match="s:element[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIP']" /> 
<xsl:template match="s:element[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse']" />
```

Now I want to use just a condition for hiding all of them instead of multiple if. Actually I use this some lines in my .xslt file for hiding my method from an special ip-address:

```
    <xsl:template match="wsdl:operation[@name = 'GetCityWeatherByZIP']">
   <xsl:variable name="rcaTrimmed" 
          select="substring-before(substring-after($remoteClientAddress, '/'), ':')" />
   <xsl:if test="not($rcaTrimmed = '192.168.3.74')">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to add all of my `**<xsl:template match**` in **a line** and then hide all of them from an special ip-address, I dont't want to write for all of my methods these codes one by one.
How can I do this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to hide everything that has a `@name` that starts with 'GetCityWeatherByZIP'?  If so, you can just use this single template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@name, 'GetCityWeatherByZIP')]">
   <xsl:variable name="rcaTrimmed" 
          select="substring-before(substring-after($remoteClientAddress, '/'), ':')" />
   <xsl:if test="not($rcaTrimmed = '192.168.3.74')">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'd also suggest moving the definition of the `rcaTrimmed` variable outside of the template so it only needs to be computed once:

```
<xsl:variable name="rcaTrimmed" 
          select="substring-before(substring-after($remoteClientAddress, '/'), ':')" />

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@name, 'GetCityWeatherByZIP')]">
   <xsl:if test="not($rcaTrimmed = '192.168.3.74')">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Also, I want to hide these: 1.GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapIn 2.GetCityWeatherByZIPSoapOut   3.GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetIn  4.GetCityWeatherByZIPHttpGetOut 5. GetCityWeatherByZIP and so on?

Comment: I have this question, for all of them I have to define a <xsl:variable name="rcaTrimmed" 
          select="substring-before(substring-after($remoteClientAddress, '/'), ':')" />

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@name, 'GetCityWeatherByZIP')]">
   <xsl:if test="not($rcaTrimmed = '192.168.3.74')">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

Comment: @user1976453 The XSLT I provided above should hide _everything_ whose name starts with "GetCityWeatherByZIP", including all 5 you listed, with just this one template. You don't need to make multiple copies of it. And no, you just need to declare the variable one time.

Comment: Thanks alot, I could got answer.